# PyVISA Error: Insufficient system resources to perform necessary memory allocation

Tags: python, gpib, pyvisa

I am using PyVISA to communicate/control a Santec TSL-550 tunable laser via GPIB-USB.

My setup was working a few days ago and everything is correctly installed (NI-VISA, NI-MAX, NI 488.2, pip installed pyvisa-py, etc.), but I received this error randomly today.

The error in the terminal and in PyCharm is the same:

**pyvisa.errors.VisaIOError:  VI_ERROR_ALLOC (-1073807300): Insufficient system resources to perform necessary memory allocation**

There are little resources online and no solution was found on the NI forum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was simple, but obscure.

The GPIB side of the GPIB-USB adapter was not connected in all the way.  I tightened it and the error was resolved.